Confusing problem with local vs class variables and rendering with silk dot net and OpenGL
I'm trying to learn/implement OpenGL using the silk.net library and I've got a rendering framework functioning. I can add a shape to the render list from my Layer update method, and I can add a shape from a collection from within that update method, but if I try to add a shape from a class field it is not rendered.
Edit: I have found that it is class fields that don't work. If I declare taskbarPanel (for example) as a field it fails to be rendered, but as a local variable inside the Update method it works fine. I'm very confused. This also makes progress impossible, because I can't implement button behaviour whilst all the components have to be created and then destroyed every update tick.
Section of Layer.class

private static List<Component> _componentsField = [];

public void Update()
{
    var taskbarPanel = new Panel("TaskbarPanel", WindowLeft, WindowTop - 30f, 0f, WindowRight, 30f, Color.Black);
    var fileButton = new Panel("FileButton", WindowLeft + 5f, WindowTop - 25f, 0f, 50f, 20f, Color.Red);
    var editButton = new Panel("EditButton", WindowLeft + 55f, WindowTop - 25f, 0f, 50f, 20f, Color.Red);
    var viewButton = new Panel("ViewButton", WindowLeft + 105f, WindowTop - 25f, 0f, 50f, 20f, Color.Green);

    // This works
    _renderer.AddShape(taskbarPanel.Name, taskbarPanel.Quad);

    // This works
    List<Component> components = [];
    componentsLocal.Add(fileButton);
    _renderer.AddShape(componentsLocal[0].Name, componentsLocal[0].Quad);

    // This doesn't work
    _componentsField.Add(editButton);
    _renderer.AddShape(_componentsField[0].Name, _componentsField[0].Quad);

    // this doesn't work
    Component[] copy = new Component[_componentsField.Count];
    Array.Copy(_componentsField.ToArray(), copy, _componentsField.Count);
    _renderer.AddShape(copy[0].Name, copy[0].Quad);
}


Section of Renderer.class

public void AddShape(string name, RenderShape shape)
{
    // Offset indices
    shape.OffsetIndices(VertexCount);

    // Increment the vertex count;
    VertexCount += shape.VertexCount;

    // Add to the dictionary if it isn't already in there.
    Shapes.TryAdd(name, shape);
}

public void Update()
{
    List<float> vertices = [];
    List<uint> indices = [];

    foreach (RenderShape shape in Shapes.Values)
    {
        vertices.AddRange(shape.Vertices);
        indices.AddRange(shape.Indices);
    }

    // Add subdata to the buffer
    VertexBuffer.BufferSubData(vertices.ToArray());
    IndexBuffer.BufferSubData(indices.ToArray());
}

public unsafe void Render()
{
    Bind();

    // Clear the frame
    OpenGL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

    // Get the indices count
    uint indicesCount = 0;
    foreach (var shape in Shapes.Values)
        indicesCount += (uint)shape.Indices.Count;

    // Draw the vertex array
    OpenGL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indicesCount, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, null);

    Unbind();
}

Section of Application.class

public Application()
{
    // Create the window options with default size and title
    WindowOptions options = WindowOptions.Default with
    {
        Size = new(800, 600),
        Title = "Notator"
    };

    // Create the window
    _window = Window.Create(options);

    // Attach methods to the window events
    _window.Load += OnLoad;
    _window.Update += OnUpdate;
    _window.Render += OnRender;
    _window.Closing += OnClosing;

    // Tell the window to run
    _window.Run();
}

private unsafe void OnLoad()
{
    // Create the renderer
    _renderer = new Renderer(_window, "Basic.shader");

    // Bind the textures
    _renderer.BindTexture("silk.png",  0);
    _renderer.BindTexture("silk2.png", 1);

    // Add layers
    _layers.Add("Taskbar", new Layer(_renderer));
}

private void OnUpdate(double deltaTime)
{
    foreach (Layer layer in _layers.Values)
    {
        layer.Update();
    }

    // update the renderer
    _renderer.Update();
}

private unsafe void OnRender(double deltaTime)
{
    // Tell the renderer to render
    _renderer.Render();
}

private void OnClosing()
{
    // Remove the renderer from OpenGL
    _renderer.Delete();
}

I can only guess that this has something to do with data addresses or something that isn't shown in the Visual Studio debugger, but I'm obviously lacking in proper understanding of OpenGL because I really have no clue how to troubleshoot and fix this.
Edited to clarify the difference between the components field and the local components variable.

Not familiar with the framework, but isn't AddShape checking to see if a shape with that name already exists? If so, you can't add the same component more than once (first that does not work) and you can't make a copy and add that unless you change the name (second does not work)

My only other suggestion is to swap taskbarPanel and editButton, make sure that the code "// This works" still does so with a different Panel and that the code "// This doesn't work" keeps failing even with the taskPanel that works elsewhere.

All the panels work if I add them the first way. That's the way I've gotten it working so I can move on to working on button stuff, which is what I actually expected to be where I ran into difficulty, not some weird variable stuff that is probably linked to the behind the scene addresses of the variables. Ultimately OpenGL wants pointers to the start of the vertex and index data sets and I presume that somewhere behind the high-level C# something is going on when inserting the data into the renderer's collections.

I suggest investigating when Renderer.Update gets invoked and why. That's the method that actually copies your vertices and indexes to the GPU for drawing. If that isn't being invoked for some reason, your geometry will be sitting in CPU memory but ignored.
OpenGL should only need the pointers to the start of the vertex and index data sets when copying (BufferData / BufferSubData). But, nasty thought, if this silk library is trying to be clever with mapping OpenGL buffers into memory, then you are absolutely right, it would break if the List got reallocated somewhere else in memory.

You say it depends on whether you declare taskbarPanel as a local or a field... but it's a local for both your "works" and "does not work" cases.  The only apparent difference is in whether the collection of panels is a local or field.

If either taskbarPanel or the collection it is within is not local it doesn't work.
